# Sound always routed through headphones jack since upgrade to 22.10

Tags: sound, audio-jack, pipewire, 22.10

Since upgrading from 22.04 to 22.10 I can't seem to get any sound through the built-in speakers and the audio seems to be constantly routed to the headphones jack. Even the DisplayPort/HDMI output won't result in any sound.

In other words: as soon as I switch to the combined internal speakers/headphones output and plug in external speakers I get a signal from the headphones jack. The Settings app correctly detects whenever a plug is inserted or pulled out (output name changes), and additionally shows output activity in the bar graph when the "Built-in Audio" is selected as output and nothing is connected to the jack.

Speakers work fine in other OSes -- including 22.04 -- as well as when booting the 22.10 live USB installer, so there's no hardware problem.

I've tried reinstalling `pipewire` and `wireplumber` but since then I've quickly run out of ideas. Some configuration seems to be missing. I tried to `dpkg-reconfigure pipewire wireplumber` but that was just a shot in the dark.

How do I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: did you get it solved? I tried forcing thru 'hdajackretask' which didnt help also

Comment: @user3041539 Unfortunately not to any greater extent than that I've stopped using Ubuntu on the machine in question.

Comment: @user3041539 It's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved by following the instructions in [an existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722961/109837).

In `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` replace

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

with

```
# options snd-hda-intel model=generic
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1
```

When doing this I also noticed that the first line existed only as a result of a previous attempt to solve this exact problem.