# No sound through speakers. Headphones work. Running Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, pipewire

I'm running Ubuntu 22.10 on an HP Zbook Fury 16 G9. I can't get sound on the laptop speakers. The headphones work fine. This was working yesterday after removing pulse audio package. It was added as a dependency of another packages.

Today it stopped working again. Headphones are fine, but speakers don't work. Rebooting does not help. Restarting pipewire, pipewire-pulse and wireplumber doesn't help.

In the settings for Sound, the speaker test does not work. But I can see movement in the sound level bar. I also see that when I play sound in a video etc.

Any idea what I can do to troubleshoot why the speakers randomly work?

Thanks,

Andy

```
wpctl status
PipeWire 'pipewire-0' [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, cookie:62023932]
 └─ Clients:
        33. pipewire                            [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:2826]
        34. WirePlumber                         [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:2825]
        35. pactl                               [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:2897]
        36. WirePlumber [export]                [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:2825]
        78. GNOME Volume Control Media Keys     [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:3626]
        79. GNOME Shell Volume Control          [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:3230]
        80. xdg-desktop-portal                  [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:3394]
        81. GNOME Settings                      [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:4391]
        96. Terminal                            [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:4501]
       103. Mutter                              [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:3230]
       104. wpctl                               [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:5732]
       110. Google Chrome input                 [0.3.58, andy@dokodemo, pid:4882]

Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      49. Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller    [alsa]
 │      50. GA104 High Definition Audio Controller [alsa]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │      55. Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller HDMI / DisplayPort 3 Output [vol: 1.00]
 │      56. Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller HDMI / DisplayPort 2 Output [vol: 1.00]
 │      57. Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller HDMI / DisplayPort 1 Output [vol: 1.00]
 │  *   58. Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller Speaker + Headphones [vol: 0.63]
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │      59. Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller Headphones Stereo Microphone [vol: 1.00]
 │  *   60. Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller Digital Microphone [vol: 1.00]
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:
        87. GNOME Settings                                              
             88. monitor_FL     
             94. monitor_FR     
             95. input_FL        < Speaker + Headphones:monitor_FL  [active]
            101. input_FR        < Speaker + Headphones:monitor_FR  [active]
       109. GNOME Settings                                              
             82. monitor_FL     
             83. monitor_FR     
             84. input_RL        < Digital Microphone:capture_RL    [active]
             86. input_FR        < Digital Microphone:capture_FR    [active]
             89. input_RR        < Digital Microphone:capture_RR    [active]
             90. input_FL        < Digital Microphone:capture_FL    [active]
             91. monitor_RR     
            100. monitor_RL     

Video
 ├─ Devices:
 │      42. HP 5MP Camera                       [v4l2]
 │      43. HP 5MP Camera                       [v4l2]
 │      44. HP 5MP Camera                       [v4l2]
 │      45. HP 5MP Camera                       [v4l2]
 │  
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │  
 ├─ Sources:
 │      51. HP 5MP Camera (V4L2)               
 │  *   53. HP 5MP Camera (V4L2)               
 │  
 ├─ Source endpoints:
 │  
 └─ Streams:

Settings
 └─ Default Configured Node Names:
         0. Audio/Sink    auto_null
```

pactl gives:

```
pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 206
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: andy
Host Name: dokodemo
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.58)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_6__source
Cookie: 03b2:68fc
```

Comment: Its working again. I ran alsamixer and selected the card sof-hda-dsp. I set "Auto-Mute Card" to disable. It remains to be seen if this really fixed it. It has been an intermittent problem.

Comment: Does it still work for you, and if so would you mind detailing the solution in an answer? Does [my similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1436754/428527) strike you as the same problem?

Comment: I don't think alsamixer was the solution. It was stable from the 17th, but then yesterday is suddenly stopped working again. I tried alsamixer settings, but that didn't change it. I ran `systemctl --user restart pipewire pipewire-pulse wireplumber` and it started working again.

Comment: I muted a youtube video and then noticed there was not sound in another tab. I tried the systemctl restart above, but no change. I went back to the muted youtube and unmuted it. Still wasn't working. Restarted Chrome. Works again. Issue in Chrome?

Comment: Sounds like a hard question to answer unless you also involved other audio sources than chrome. If the new audio stack with its shiny new security model can be sabotaged by any random client then that's pretty funny. I don't use chrome though.

Answer (score 0):

I [solved my similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/1452421/428527) with Intel audio using a solution found in another answer.

Mine is probably not the same exact issue (I never got any sound no matter what), but might be worth mentioning it here for anyone else who's searching around.